# How can we remove duplicate children value from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

te = [
      {
        "Name": "Bala",
        "phone": "None"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bala",
        "phone": "None"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bala",
        "phone": "None"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bala",
        "phone": "None"
      }
    ]

Comment: I have value="1400-SEND-MAP1" repeated which I want remove.

Comment: you first need to reformat the code to let other people read.

Comment: from, you are getting this from php?
if yes then you can add check their help.
any more help therichpost..

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to remove "value": "1400-SEND-MAP1" which is repeated in above JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you just want to traverse the structure and find any duplicates on different levels. This is not the best solution but it works:
 check every entry/node in the JSON

- Traverse all entities/nodes check if they have the field "value"

  - If it is a unique entity/node push to an array to keep track of the
    unique keys.
  - If it is not a unique key keep traversing but in the way
    back remove it.

It seems that the function `delete` is putting nulls on the deleted entity/node. 
after the function, I convert the JSON to a string then remove all `"nulls,"`
and `",nulls,"`

```
let json = yourJson;
let uniqueValues = [];
let jsonWithoutDuplicates = removeDuplicates(x);
jsonWithoutDuplicates = JSON.stringify(jsonWithoutDuplicates)
  .replace(/null,/g,'')
  .replace(/,null,/g,',');
console.log(jsonWithoutDuplicates) // you can convert it back to json if you want


function removeDuplicates(json) {
  for (var i in json) {
    if (json[i] !== null && typeof(json[i]) === "object") {
      let objValue = json[i].value;

      if(objValue){
        if(uniqueValues.indexOf(objValue) === -1){
          uniqueValues.push(objValue);
          removeDuplicates(json[i]);
        }else{
          removeDuplicates(json[i]);
          delete json[i]
        }
      }else{
        removeDuplicates(json[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return json;
}
```

Code: https://playcode.io/141053[code](https://playcode.io/141053?tabs=console&script.js&output)

Comment: Thanks For the solution, above is removing duplicate from same level not from next or previous level.